# Any software which can filter the files in a directory

Tags: windows, file-filter

Is there any software by which if i type anything in the seach box and shows those files matched (in particular directory)  and then i can copy or paste only those files.

OS:Windows

Comment: Can you add more details, in particular your operating system.

Comment: @Nick Josevski - Mirage is usually asking Windows-related questions, but you're right, more info always looks better. :)

Comment: @Molly going with probability, it's probably Windows.

Comment: yes its windows

Comment: @Molly thanks for that, didn't think to check the trend of questions asked by Mirage, otherwise would have just added a tag with my level of edit reputation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Total Commander](http://www.ghisler.com/)** can do that.

Just open the "particular directory", go to **Command** > **Search...** then type the filename (or wildcards) into the search box and click **Start Search**. TC will show all matching results, click **Feed to Listbox**. From there you may copy and paste the files.

(of course, since you're using TC, you wouldn't have to *paste* as TC does it all in one go :)

Comment: Can i use other wild card "#" to filter results . * is pretty vague

Comment: @Mirage - Total Commander Help (top right corner or F1), click Search, type wildcard and in the result box open "Dialog box:Search:General" ... it's all there.

Answer (score 0):

On a Linux system the rox-filer program selects files matching a glob (*.html etc.) or meeting certain conditions (IsReg, IsLink, IsChar, IsPipe, IsDir, IsMine etc.) or comparisons ("Before n hours/weeks/years ago" "> n Gb/Mb" "< n Mb/Kb/bytes" etc.) if you type "?".

Answer (score 0):

[Far Manager](http://farmanager.com) can do this as well. Which might be preferrable since it doesn't come as shareware anymore (and OFMs look weird in non-text mode ;-)).